# Problema al leer JSON desde Instrumento IOT

Tags: javascript, json, mqtt

Hola es mi primera pregunta así que por favor no me castiguen tanto, resulta que estoy leyendo datos desde un instrumento IOT que me envía datos a mi server MQTT  envía 32 paquetes separados con un formato que no se puede cambiar, no tengo problemas para leer los encabezados pero no puedo separar los datos aquí una de las formas que estoy tratando de utilizar.

```
if(topic == 'hypo:JSON'){
    var msg = JSON.parse(message.toString());        
    console.log(msg.TIME);
    console.log(msg.RG0);
    console.log(msg.RG1[1].V);
}
```

Este otro ejemplo tampoco me funciona y me da el mismo error (respuesta de [Yussef](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/301324/yussef))

```
var message = 
`{"ID":"00000001","PID":"RG81","CH":4,"START":0,"TIME":"2022-09-26 
10:51:07","RG0":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG1":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG2": 
{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG3":{"S":2,"V":0.000}}`;

var msg = JSON.parse(message.toString());  
console.log(msg.RG1.V);
//o tambien 
console.log(msg.RG1['V']);
```

Datos que envía el equipos cada 15 segundos (solo me sirve el que viene en "V":

{"ID":"00000001","PID":"RG81","CH":4,"START":0,"TIME":"2022-09-26 10:51:07","RG0":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG1":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG2":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG3":{"S":2,"V":0.000}}

[image: Código de error]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes llaves {} es un objetos y lees sus propiedades con un punto, si su propiedad es otro objeto pues sigues poniendo puntos. Los array son con corchetes [], y ahí podrías haber puesto RG1[1].V

```js
var message = `{"ID":"00000001","PID":"RG81","CH":4,"START":0,"TIME":"2022-09-26 10:51:07","RG0":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG1":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG2":{"S":2,"V":0.000},"RG3":{"S":2,"V":0.000}}`;

var msg = JSON.parse(message.toString());   

console.log(msg.RG1.V);

//o tambien

console.log(msg.RG1['V']);
```

Comment: Si ya lo había intentado y no funciona me da el mismo error, por eso recurrí a ver si a alguien más le había pasado.

Comment: @CristianSanchez Prueba lo que puse, y si te aparece error actualiza tu pregunta, añadiendo esta prueba